# Proper way to automatically update bound datagrid (non ugly way)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatable

I'm looking for a proper way to automatically update a bound datagrid in a "non ugly way". I have a wpf application with a datagrid which i have bound to a datatable:

```
MeasurementResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = _main.CurrentMeasurement.MeasurementDataTable.AsDataView();
```

Pretty straightforward! Next is that I have used the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` to synchronize the model with the UI:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MeasurementDataSet.MeasurementDataTable MeasurementDataTable 
    {
        get
        {
            return _measurementDataTable;
        }
        set
        {
            _measurementDataTable = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MeasurementDataTable");
        } 
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

A thread is adding new rows to the datatable and giving no errors whatsoever. As a little expected, the DataGrid is not updating/"refreshing" as the thread updates the table. What is the best way to do this? I rather not use a separate timer/thread to update the datagrid with : datagrid.refresh(); & datagrid rebind..

I have searched a lot on this, and it seems i am on the right track, but missing i think some crucial parts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching and trying the suggested answers, i have implemented the second part of the answer of @coder0815 and used the Observable Collection instead of the DataTable. It seems that now i don't have to implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface and the UI gets updated automatically!

Only watch out if you try to update the collection if you created the collection on the UI Thread, what most of the time happens in WPF. In WPF < 4.5 you have to use delegates to surpass the "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread" exception. If you have WPF > 4.5, you can use the following:

Create a variable on the UI thread, for instance:

private SynchronizationContext _uiContext;

In your creating of the UI, initialize the value:

_uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

Now you can easily use to update the collection using the following:

_uiContext.Send(x => YOUR_METHOD(), null);

Replace the YOUR_METHOD with the method you have on the collection!

Comment: For your question this is not the best way. It's the same as using delegates, and I think `SynchronizationContext` is available since .Net 2.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't bind to the return value of a method, because then the return value gets copied and will never change.

Bind your ItemsSource to a Property of a Type which implements **INotifyPropertyChanged**.
In your case, I suggest to use a **ObservableCollection**. There you have the benefit that if the items stored inside the collection are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and beeing changed the UI gets updated without calling **refresh()** or **rebind()**.

Comment: The first is not true, if i manually refresh the datagrid, the results are all shown. The second i agree, but i was hoping to use the datatable instead of a ObservableCollection..

Comment: If you update manually it will work of course, but thats not what Databinding is meant for. Usually you bind it to a property properly and have no longer to worry about updating the UI

Answer (score 0):

You could add one property:

```
    public DataView  MeasurementDataTableView 
    {
        get
        {
            return MeasurementDataTable.AsDataView();
        }           
    }
```

Then use this as the ItemsSource (not sure if this will work, if not, I think you can just set it with the XAML code using binding):

```
MeasurementResultsDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, "MeasurementDataTableView") ;
```

So that you can add `NotifyPropertyChanged("MeasurementDataTableView")` after adding new rows to the datatable.